# Grails form submit without changing the view

Tags: grails, form-submit, gsp

I want to call an action (it does some filtering and send mails) from my GSP but I want to stay on that GSP. How to acoplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Ajax to submit your form.

Use the [formRemote](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) tag to achieve an Ajax submit.

Alternatively you could build it on your own by hooking into the `onSubmit` event of you form.

Comment: I am not sure when this happened, but the `formRemote` tag is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with a form, you can take a look on 'submitToRemote' tag: [submitToRemote](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html)

but if you want to do it with a hyperlink... take a look on 'remoteLink' tag: [remoteLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html)